# Pass data to React component with kefirjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactive-programming, kefir.js

I am new in ReactJS and "reactive programming". I tried to create a dispatcher, action and store according to [this](https://github.com/pqr/react-flux-kefir-es6-todomvc-example) project, but I don't know how to pass data to component.

In [this](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/14595/) example it doesn't work.

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var AppDispatcher = Kefir.emitter();

function DataActions() {
    this.getAllData = function () {
        AppDispatcher.emit({
            actionType: "GET_ALL"
        });
    };
}

var Actions = new DataActions();

var getAllDataActionsStream = AppDispatcher.filter(function (action) {
    return action.actionType === "GET_ALL";
}).map(function (action) {
    return function (data) {
        return data;
    };
});

var dataStream = Kefir.merge([getAllDataActionsStream]).scan(function (prevData, modificationFunc) {
    return modificationFunc(prevData);
}, {});

var Content = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        this.onDataChange = this.onDataChange.bind(this);
        return {componentData: []};
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        dataStream.onValue(this.onDataChange);
    },
    componentWillMount: function(){
        dataStream.offValue(this.onDataChange);
        console.log(Actions.getAllData());
    },
    onDataChange(newData) {
        this.setState({componentData: newData});
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log(this.state);
        var list = this.state.componentData.map(function (item, i) {
            return (
                <li key={i}>{item}</li>
            );
        });

        return <ul>{list}</ul>;
    }
});

React.render(<Content />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Can you check via debugger or console log if the data gets lost on it's way from the actions to Kefir or from Kefir to the component?

Comment: @Moezalez they are lost from actions to Kefir. 'AppDispatcher' doesn't emit the action. https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/15496/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I begin to answer in length I want to answer this part up front:

> but I don't know how to pass data to component.

In the example you linked the author passes in the Todos into the main component using React's [props](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html), not with an action.  So that is the approach I take in my example as well.

[Now here is my example. I highly reccommend looking at the example and reading along to what I've written below.](https://jsfiddle.net/sthagman/zjcdsd84/3/)

```
var data = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];

// This will now log all events of the AppDispatcher in the console with the prefix 'Kefer: '
var AppDispatcher = Kefir.emitter().log("Kefir: ");

function DataActions() {

    // Our application has an action of emitting a random number.
    this.emitNumber = function() {
        AppDispatcher.emit({
            actionType: "EMIT_NUMBER"
        })
    };
}

var Actions = new DataActions();

var emitNumberActionStream = AppDispatcher
        .filter(function(action) {
            return action.actionType === "EMIT_NUMBER";
        })
        .map(function(action) {
            console.log("EMIT_NUMBER ACTION OCCURRED!!");
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (10)) + 1;
        });

// Only one stream, no need to merge right now.
//var dataStream = Kefir.merge([ getAllDataActionsStream ]);


var Content = React.createClass({
            getInitialState:   function() {

                // Set initial componentData using the data passed into this component's via props
                return { componentData: this.props.data };
            },
            componentDidMount: function() {

                // On each emitted value run the this.onDataChange function
                emitNumberActionStream.onValue(this.onDataChange);

                // Every second emit a number using the Actions we created earlier
                setInterval(function() {
                    Actions.emitNumber();
                }, 1000);
            },
            onDataChange:      function(emittedNumber) {

                console.log('state on change:', this.state);

                // Update the state by appending the emitted number to the current state's componentData
                this.setState({ componentData: this.state.componentData.concat([emittedNumber])});
                console.log('updated state: ', this.state);
                console.log('-----------------');
            },
            render:            function() {
                console.log('RENDER AGAIN!');

                var list = this.state.componentData.map(function(item, i) {
                    return (
                            <li key={i}>{item}</li>
                    );
                });

                return <ul>{list}</ul>;
            }
        })
        ;

// Pass in initial data using props 'data={data}'
React.render(<Content data={data}/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

I modified the example you gave that wasn't working so that it works and makes a little more sense (hopefully).

The Actions and Stores work like this:

Actions:

- Request a number be emitted

Stores

- Listen for "EMIT_NUMBER" actions and emit a random number

And the actual component runs like this:

1. It gets the initial 5 numbers passed into the component via props.
2. Once mounted it begins listening to the store and creates a setInterval that calls the action dispatcher's emitNumber() action.  The interval is to show the reactivity at work, you could imagine that there was a button to press that would call emitNumber() instead.
3. The store observes the action dispatcher emit "EMIT_NUMBER" and emits a number.
4. The component observes the store emitted a number and updates the component's state.
5. The component observes that its state has changed and it rerenders.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sam. Let me ask you one thing. If you want to emit action in `getInitialState ` function, why it doesn't work? https://jsfiddle.net/zjcdsd84/6/

Comment: The emit action is working in that example.  You are trying to capture the emitted number with `var number = Actions.emitNumber();` but `.emitNumber()` doesn't return anything, it just tells the emitter to emit an event.  To capture the number you need to subscribe to the `emitNumberActionStream` [using any of kefir's ways](http://rpominov.github.io/kefir/#main-methods) of subscribing.

[Look here.](https://jsfiddle.net/sthagman/zjcdsd84/7/) The emit works, but happens before the first render and before `emitNumberActionStream.onValue(..)`, so the emitted number isn't observed.

Comment: Kefir.emitter is [not supported](https://github.com/rpominov/kefir/issues/88) anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that you're using ES6 syntax (which is what the example was written in... notice the [Readme](https://github.com/pqr/react-flux-kefir-es6-todomvc-example#todomvc-example-build-with-react-flux-kefirjs-and-es6)). You'll need to either use a transpiler like [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) or convert your `method(param => console.log(param))` syntax into normal JS (ie, `method(function(param) { console.log(param) });`).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't posted transpiled version. Please see my edited post.